# 500 URL ReWrite Module Error IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I have a few websites that use to be on a server using iis7 as the host.  I have moved these websites to a new server that is IIS8 and the database has been upgraded from SQL 2005 to SQL 2014.

Another part of this change is it now runs through a DMZ reverse proxy that redirects to an internal server.

This works fine in Chrome or Edge. But Firefox and IE I get a 500 URL Rewrite Module Error.  Not much more information in the error other than that.

I have other sites on the reverse proxy that work with no issue.  But all of the ones that work are .net 4.0 or higher.  The sites I  am having issue with are both 3.5 framework.

I have tried setting the app pool framework on the dmz to match the internal server.

There are currently 2 inbound rules one converts http to https and the other is the proxy rule.  There is 1 Outbound rule which is also part of the revers proxy.  The reverse proxy currently takes the https traffic and uses http internally and then the outbound sends it back as https.  This is that same on all of the site on this server that currently work without any issues.

Some more information.  I turned of error tracing and the fuller error I received is 
Outbound rewrite rules cannot be applied when the content of the HTTP response is encoded ("gzip").

Answer (score 2):

This is because the responses that are coming from the back end server are using HTTP Compression, and URL rewrite cannot modify a response that is already compressed. This causes a processing error for the outbound rule resulting in the 500.52 status code.

There are two ways to work around this: either you turn off compression on the backend server that is delivering the HTTP responses (which may or may not be possible, depending on your configuration), or we attempt to indicate to the backend server the client does not accept compressed responses by removing the header when the request comes into the IIS reverse proxy and by placing it back when the response leaves the IIS server

There are a number of step needed to complete this fix you can find them and all the information you need at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-part-2-dealing-with-500-52-status-codes/ 
It is a 3 part post and the second post in the series was the solution.

Comment: Answers on SO must stand on their own. Links should supplement a complete, self-contained answer. Please add the relevant "fix" information to your answer.

Comment: it is responses like this that makes this my last source or place to ask a question. I had a question and was looking for answers but rather then when I find an answer I post it to help anyone who may also have the same issue. But in what has become to common in the stack overflow community rather than helping they prefer to belittle  and act superior to anyone looking for help.  Thanks again for showing my this is my last place to look for help.

Comment: Links can go dead. So if possible, copy and paste some of the steps or leave enough hints for someone who might read this in the future but cannot access that linked page any more. If you do want to help someone else, make it complete and that's what @canon kindly asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you also have the [rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) installed on your instance or you'll face a 500 error